# Output only on return value not null in PHP

Tags: php, return-value

I am writing a return value into a temp value to evaluate it:

```
function get_me_something() {
 do something with $result;
 return $result;
}

echo get_me_something;
```

What I would like is to echo only if value is NOT 0

```
$temp = get_me_something;
$temp != 0 ? echo $temp : "";
```

Is it possible to echo only on certain value?

Comment: Would this work: `echo get_me_something() ?: ''`?  (`$a ?: $b` is shorthand for `$a ? $a : $b` and exists in PHP 5.3+) It will check if the function's return value is "truthy" (http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) and then print the value if it is, otherwise it prints nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
$temp = get_me_something();
echo $temp !== 0 ? $temp : "";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use echo you will always output something ( even empty ), and it's a bad pratice to use echo when you maybe are not expecting to output anything.

You can do:

```
if(($return = get_me_something()) !== 0)
{
  echo $return;
}
```

The if statement will both assign `get_me_something()` to `$return` and use `$return` as part of the comparison.